# Measuring Contrast of an Image using Python

Tags: python-imaging-library, measure, contrast

I have a code for brightness, and im currently looking into measuring contrast

```
from PIL import Image
from math import sqrt
imag = Image.open("../Images/noise.jpg")

imag = imag.convert ('RGB')
imag.show()

X,Y = 0,0

pixelRGB = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
R,G,B = pixelRGB
brightness = sum([R,G,B])/3 ##0 is dark (black) and 255 is bright (white)
print(brightness)
print(R,G,B)
```

Surely contrast could be something similiar to this code, any ideas would be great, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Different folks have different ideas of contrast... one method is to look at the difference between the brightest and darkest pixel in the image, another is to look at the standard deviation of the pixels away from the mean. There are other statistics too. Note that it requires looking at **all** the pixels in the image - not just the first.

The simplest way to look at the statistics of an image is to use PIL's `ImageStat` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageStat

# Load image
im = Image.open('image.png')

# Calculate statistics
stats = ImageStat.Stat(im)                                                                 

for band,name in enumerate(im.getbands()): 
    print(f'Band: {name}, min/max: {stats.extrema[band]}, stddev: {stats.stddev[band]}')
```

So, if I create a greyscale image like this with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 1024x768 gradient:"rgb(64,64,64)-rgb(200,200,200)" -depth 8 image.png
```

and run the above code, I get:

```
Band: L, min/max: (64, 200), stddev: 39.31443755161709
```

If I create a magenta-black gradient:

```
magick -size 1024x768 gradient:magenta-black -depth 8 image.png
```

and run the code, I get:

```
Band: R, min/max: (0, 255), stddev: 73.68457550034924
Band: G, min/max: (0, 0), stddev: 0.0
Band: B, min/max: (0, 255), stddev: 73.68457550034924
```

If the min and max are close, the contrast is low. If the min and max are widely spaced, the contrast is high. Likewise the standard deviation, as it measures how *"spread out"* the pixels are across the histogram.